# Bake animation along a curve to keyframes

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

is it possible to bake an animation along a curve to keyframes??

I've been trying to create a snake  like movement of an object that curves on a the bazier but the result is that the object only follow the path and not curving with it. Pls help!

[image]
basically bake this animation with the curving to keyframes

Comment: seen a post here that uses a script, but it does not work for 2.8
https://blenderartists.org/t/converting-animation-on-a-path-to-keyframes/604710/7

Comment: Mesh deformation is usually baked to cache like Alembic, MDD, PC2, etc.
The only "keyframeable" way is by using *Anim All* addon, which is shipped with Blender.

Comment: although Animall is a nice addon but it doesn't serve the purpose for me, 
so I am rephrasing... is it possible to bake to keyframes that will be running when exporting to GLB?  
could I bake to alembic and convert it to glb using another piece of software?.

Comment: You can convert it to keyframed shape keys by export it to mdd then reimport it and export the whole model to the ominous format. https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-convert-a-cloth-simulation-animation-to-keyframes/600133

Comment: thanks! will test it